# How to open Main App withe parameters in a helper app?

Tags: cocoa

There is a helper app for my Project, both main App and helper app are in sandbox. The main App may be not running so i can not post distributed notification in helper App. And i found that helper App has no permission to set Userdefaults of main App.
So the only thing i can do is to open main App in the helper App with a parameter. 
I can use below to do this.

`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.mainApp" options:0 additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil launchIdentifier:nil];`

So how can i pass and get the parameter between the two apps?

Answer (score 0):

Use [app groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19), so both apps will share access to special container (with a settings plist file for example).